# Custom error for view-model int overflow (invalid values)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my model I have an nullable int.

In the view I have an input of type 'number'.

The problem is that the user could possibly input a number larger than the maximum possible integer value, which results in the following error:

The value [value] is not valid for [field]

I want to change this message, and putting a [Range(...)] validation on the attribute does not help, as non of my validations are being called, because the framework cannot parse the value to an int.

--------- EDIT ---------

My validations perform normally at normal input as shown here:

[image]

What I mean about my validations not being called is that I've read that the if the framework fails to parse the value to an int (because the value exceeds the max value of an integer), it ignores any further "unnecessary" validation.

Therefore my Range validation is ignored, as shown here:

[image]

I've tried creating a custom ValidationAttribute, but that has the same behaviour (Being called correctly at normal integer input, but is ignored at overflowing integer input)

--------- /EDIT ---------

All the solutions I have seen, proposes binding a custom resource file, in which I could override the default message for invalid values.

But I want to be able to specify a custom message at each attribute in case of an invalid value.

I thought about using strings instead of ints, and creating a custom ValidationAttribute which tries to parse it to an int.

Are there any alternatives?

// EDIT: I could avoid this problem (to some degree) by having client-side validation - But I want to know if it is possible from the server-side, in case of someone editing the html and forcing a higher value

Comment: What do you mean _none of my validations are being called_? If your code is correct they will be called. You need to show your code.

Comment: It works fine for me (refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JqDFbq)). If you enter `9999999999999` the range validation message is displayed as soon as you tab out of the control.

Comment: But that is with client-side validation - Which partly solves the problem, but I want server-side validation..

Comment: You are getting server side validation (but maybe not the way you expect). What is happening is the `DefaultModelBinder` tries to set the value to `9999999999999` which it cant, so the _value is not valid_ error is added to `ModelState` (the 'Range' condition is not even checked because there is no point)

Comment: Exactly - So my question still remains, how can I (if I can) override that default message, and if so, can I set different messages to different attributes?

Comment: AFAIK, you cant. If the value is not valid for the type, then no other validation checks are done. But if you want to change the default error message for an invalid value, then you can use a resource file (but its global, so having it display a message relating to a range would not make much sense)

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of ways in which you can validate user input:

- proper usage of Data Annotations - you could take a look here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6 and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(v=vs.100).aspx
- usage of jQuery Validation - http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Here is an example of custom validation attribute:

```
public class MyIntegerValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string[] PropertyNames { get; }

    public MyIntegerValidationAttribute(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        PropertyNames = propertyNames;
    }    

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var properties = this.PropertyNames.Select(validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty);

        //here you have values of your properties 
        var values = properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null)).OfType<int>();

        if (YOUR_CUSTOM_CONDITION)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    [MyIntegerValidationAttribute("B", "C", ErrorMessage = "My error message")]
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use data annotations as pr. my post (See edit), also I want server-side validation (Also see edit)

Comment: I've updated my answer by example implementation of custom validation attribute which should solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but using your exact code, I still get the default error message. See these two images: http://i.imgur.com/gkY2HVO.png and http://i.imgur.com/U2d8ffC.png

Comment: Try to turn off any other validation on that field and just use that custom attribute (perform all validation checks inside that attribute).

Comment: I had no other validation - I used your exact ViewModel